# Draw an image and a stem plot in 3d with matpltolib

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I'm trying to make a 3d plot with python that shows an image at a certain level and certain specific points as a stem plot (basically the image is a sort of 2d map and the stem plots represent the value of a certain parameter at the point in the map)

Current code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.exp(-(X**2) - Y**2)

x0 = [-0.5, 0, 0.5]
y0 = [-0.5, 0, 0.5]
z0 = [0.5, 1, 2]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection="3d"))
ax.contourf(
    x,
    y,
    z,
    zdir="z",
    offset=-0.0,
)
ps = ax.stem(x0, y0, z0)
for p in ps:
    p.set_zorder(20)

plt.show()
```

I added the `set_zorder()` part to try to put the stem plot forward, however the resulting plot looks like this:
[image: h]

Where the lines are hidden behind the 2d image while I would like it to look like the stem where originating on the 2d plot.

Random image I've found on the internet to explicate what I'm trying to achieve (with bars instead of stem plots because I couldn't find one with stem plots).
Many thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `computed_zorder` kwarg to control this. By setting that to `False`, a 3D axes will respect the `zorder` values that you set. The default is `True`, which tries to work out what they should be.

See the docs [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.html).

The code to change is your example is:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection="3d", computed_zorder=False))
```

which yields:

[image]

Comment: Ah didn't realise this type of control existed. Should have read the docs more carefully, thanks.

Comment: Its a (reasonably) new feature, only been there since around version 3.5 I think